# What is acctually .val().trigger('change') doing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm confused by this line in my project:

This id: `categories-product` belong to `<select>` and I've seen in project someone wrote this: And I'm wondering what this basically means ?

```
$('#categories-product').val(product.category.id).trigger('change');
```

Please could anyone explain me this?

Thanks

Comment: Sets as value the category id and then triggers the event `change` bound to the element `categories-product`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trigger('change')` will actually allow the javascript runtime to execute the change event for the element. If you have associated any `change` event to that element then this will allow to explicitly trigger that change event.

Actually, the work of `trigger()` is to just execute all handlers and behaviours attached to the matched elements for the given event type. And specifying the event name as a parameter will only trigger that event. Like,

```
trigger('change') //triggers the change event listener only

trigger('click') //triggers the click event listener only
```

So, your code

`('#categories-product').val(product.category.id).trigger('change');`

Will set the value of the `#categories-product` and then this will explicitly trigger the `change` event so that the `change` action that is associated with this element is executed.

Answer (score 3):

Most jQuery methods provide *chaining* by returning `this` (which is the jQuery set you called the method on). This is an absolutely key part of the jQuery API. `val` is one of those methods. So that code is doing this:

```
$('#categories-product').val(product.category.id);
$('#categories-product').trigger('change');
```

...but without having to look up the element a second time.

So it's setting the value of the select, and then triggering the `change` event on it (presumably so handlers for that event do something).

Answer (score 1):

To understand it better you can break this line in 2 statements

```
$('#categories-product').val(product.category.id);
$('#categories-product').trigger('change');
```

Now, it is clear that the first line sets the value and second line triggers the change event. The above is just a shorthand way of clubbing the statements into one statement.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a drop down i-e `select` tag in your DOM with id as `categories-product`.

And

```
$('#categories-product').val(product.category.id).trigger('change');
```

is setting some value as selected value and then triggering a change event so that if there is any listener added for change event on that selector, the callback should be executed

Comment: so if there is in the code something like  `$(#categories-product').on('change'` ,... this will be executed because of `.trigger('change');` ?

Comment: Yes that will get executed

Answer (score 1):

It is called Chaining in Jquery, find more details at [Jquery Chaining](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp). It is equivalent to

```
$('#categories-product').val(product.category.id);
$('#categories-product')..trigger('change');
```